# Creating a material spinner dropdown in android using MDC

Tags: android, material-design, mdc-components

I was looking into Material design Material.io for material components, everything was well and good, I was trying to use MDC's TextField component
to create a material drop down spinner, but I could not seem to find any related documentation, is it possible to create a spinner using MDC? if so, where can I find documentations for it?

is saw a spinner in there catalog for TextField, can I do something like this?:

[image]

Comment: try applying this theme to your spinner `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox"`

Comment: yeah tried that, does not seem to work, even wraped it with the material layout.

Comment: Okay then another approach would be like patch but will work, use `TextInputLayout` with above style, and inside of it's `EditText` take right drawable as drop-down icon, make everything editable false and open popup menu on click of it. It'll function exactly like what you wanted

Comment: hacky, but workable. ill use that for now, thanks.

Comment: Sure, will dig deeper and find something, let know if there's something. Also let me know if stuck at anything.

Comment: Check out answer from @petyr, it's working solution from Google's material design page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Material Design website its marked as Planned for Android ([Material Menus](https://material.io/design/components/menus.html#implementation)) I also noticed Material Design's [Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/materialdesign/status/1058041043130769408) it's just been released for Web. So hopefully an actual implementation will be released soon.

Answer (score 20):

This is exactly what you need for this

https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/#exposed-dropdown-menus

first you add the AutocompleteTextView in the Textinputlayout

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Then you can design the menu items like so:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"/>
```

Initialize the adadpter in java like:

```
String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
        new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getContext(),
            R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item,
            COUNTRIES);

AutoCompleteTextView editTextFilledExposedDropdown =
    view.findViewById(R.id.filled_exposed_dropdown);
editTextFilledExposedDropdown.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You can change the styles to meet various variations like:

Filled
`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"`

outlined

Apply this style to your TextInputLayout:

`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"`

Dense Filled

Apply this style to your TextInputLayout:

`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"`

Dense Outlined

Apply this style to your TextInputLayout:

`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"`

Comment: Can you mention the dependency for `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu`

Comment: add this to your gradle implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09"

Comment: How can I avoid the keyboard input to this EditText ?

Comment: How to set one item in the list to be selected by default and still show the entire list items? I tried setting an item in the list but while selecting the drop-down it's only showing that selected item.

Comment: @KavinRajuS how did you set the item to be the selected item

Comment: @petyr In Kotlin: ```binding.dropdownMenu.apply {

           this.setText(LIST_COUNTRIES.get(0), false)
           this.setAdapter(adapter)
        }``` 
So it's basically by calling the ```setText("Default Value", false)``` function.

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada can you find a solution for blocking input?

Comment: how to retrive the selected value from AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: @Akashkumar You can use various different methods, you can use databinding and bind the text to a variable, or use an onItemSelectedListener

Comment: @petyr  setOnItemClickListener(object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

                override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, position: Int, p3: Long) {}  }

Comment: use setOnItemSelectedListener not onItemClicked @Akashkumar

Comment: IMHO the suggested way of implementing a `Spinner` in MDC is horrible.  The exposed dropdown menu approach just seems to be an `EditText` that has an autocomplete functionality, coupled with a predefined list of choices for the autocomplete.  My `Spinner` implementation shows both text *and* a graphical symbol (using a custom `Adapter`)... both in the dropdown *and* as the selected choice.  This doesn't seem possible with MDC because the underlying UI element is just an `EditText` (i.e. purely text based).

Comment: @petyr it actually depends. If the `AutoCompleteTextView` is not editable, `setOnItemSelectedListener` won't work at all. In that situation you have to use `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: Thank you @Xam, I didn't know that. I will check that out and maybe update the answer.

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada try disabling autoCompleteTextView it work for me

                    (android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:inputType="none")

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want the layout work like spinner (not an editText)

Layout xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_gender"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/gender" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Extension Code:

```
fun <T> MaterialAutoCompleteTextView.applyDropdown(
    items: List<Pair<String, T>>,
    onSelect: (item: Pair<String, T>) -> Unit = {},
) {
    setSimpleItems(items.map { it.first }.toTypedArray())
    threshold = items.map { it.first }.maxOf { it.length }.plus(1)
    isCursorVisible = false
    isFocusable = false
    isFocusableInTouchMode = false
    inputType = InputType.TYPE_NULL
    onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
        items.getOrNull(position)?.let { onSelect(it) }
    }
}

val items = listOf(Pair("Male", "male"), Pair("Female", "female"))
binding.dropdownGender.applyDropdown(items) {
    //do something with it.second --> (male, female)
}
```