# onItemSelected() for a Spinner is always triggered when app come from background

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a viewpager (hold by an Activity) with several fragments that are never destroyed. When I switch the application to the background, all my fragments change to the `onStop()` state. When the application returns to foreground, the current fragment is `onResume()` but not the others. But on the other hand, I still pass in the `onItemSelected()` of my spinner when I'm not even on the fragment containing it.

Comment: Show us what have you tried>

Comment: Spinners are buggy. Don't use it. Consider using ExposedDropdownMenu from the material components

Comment: It's true that this is not the first time I've been embarrassed with spinners ^^

Comment: @sonnet thanks i will try this component

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54004976/in-android-how-to-create-an-outlined-dropdown-menu-spinner-as-specified-by-th

Comment: it doesn't actually fix my problem because it's just style. Nevertheless, thank you because my spinner is prettier now.

Comment: That link is not just about style. ExposedDropdownMenu works (and is defined) differently than a Spinner. See your relevant spinner issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event

Comment: I solved my problem by checking if my adapter was not null. Because I was actually adding a new adapter for my spinner every time... sorry